# What does 'qu'est-ce que' litteraly means?

Tags: questions

Am I understanding correctly, that difference of these two questions 'Es-tu allé à la ville?' and 'Qu'est-ce que tu es allé à la ville?' is 'Did you go to the town' and '**Is this true, that** you went to the town?' ?

Comment: *Qu'est-ce que tu as allé à la ville* is incorrect. Are you sure you don't mean "est-ce que tu es allé à la ville" ?

Comment: *Aller à la ville* sounds old fashioned, would be *es-tu allé en ville* nowadays. The second sentence might also be *Qu'est-ce que tu es allé faire en ville*.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, ‘Qu'est-ce que tu es allé à la ville’ is wrong.
To answer your question, qu’est-ce que literally means ‘what  is this which’ or ‘what is this that’.
Qu’est-ce que translates to ‘what’ when it is used as an interrogative for a direct object. For example: Qu'est-ce que tu fais ? - What are you doing/What do you do?
It translates to ‘what is’ when it is used as an interrogative for a definition. For example: Qu'est-ce qu'un blog ? - What is a blog? 
I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Affirmative question

> — Tu vas à la piscine ?  — Oui, j'aime la natation. (Agreeing — you
>   will go)
>
> — Tu vas à la piscine ?  — Non, je déteste la natation. (Disagreeing —
>   you will not go)

Negative question

> — Tu ne vas pas à la piscine ?  — Non, je déteste la natation.
>   (Agreeing — you will not go)
>
> — Tu ne vas pas à la piscine ?  — Si, j'aime la natation. (Disagreeing
>   — you will go)

Note that all of these are the informal style of asking questions (i.e. like declarative sentences but with a rising intonation).
The most formal way is by inversion.

> Ne vas-tu pas à la piscine ?

For your question in particular:

> — Es-tu allé en ville ? — Oui, j'y suis allé/ Non, je n'y suis pas
>   allé.

A less informal way is with the est-ce que structure:

> Est-ce que tu ne vas pas à la piscine ?

As @jlliagre note

> Qu'est-ce que tu es allé faire en ville ?

is acceptable.

A formal version could be:

> Qu'es-tu allé faire en ville ?